# Image caching in when using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

its common place to use javascript like in this exsample:

Example: http://www.htmlite.com/JS019.php

My question is: Does the second image download each time or is it cached when the page first loads. If so how does the server know to cache the image?

Comment: Yes is cached, and this have to do with the client browser, and not the server. To be stay on cache on a second page reload have to do with the headers of the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking if the image is cached in your browser or in the server?

In both cases, the answer would be yes if cache is on.

Basically, your server knows the image must be put in cache when it receives a request from a client asking to download this image. So the behavior is the same with or without javascript on your HTML page. This only applies in the case where cache is activated on the server, obviously.